# What's new() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm studying the [WebRTC tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#6) from Google's codelab.

In its `index.js` section for Node.js. I has the following line.

```
var fileServer = new(nodeStatic.Server)();
```

I understand `new` is an operator to create instances. But it above is using `new(nodeStatic.Server)()` which confuses me.

Can someone please explain it for me? Thanks.

Comment: `nodeStatic.Server` is a constructor. `new` invokes it.

Comment: It's `new` + `(nodeStatic.Server)`. You could omit the parenthesis and it wouldn't make a difference. And probably you should, as they are confusing indeed.

Comment: Thank! zerkms and Bergi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nodeStatic.Server` is apparently a constructor.  So, your code works like this;

```
let serverConstructor = nodeStatic.Server;
let fileServer = new serverConstructor();
```

The parens are used in your original code to make the competing precedence between `new`, `()` and the `.` operator a little more obvious.  You'd have to study the precedence rules in the Javascript spec to see if the parens around `nodeStatic.Server` are actually needed or not (it appears they are not, but it takes some detailed knowledge of the spec or running your own tests to know that).

Comment: That's explained very clearly. Thanks! Will accept it as answer.

Comment: I just think the extra parenthesis are confusing. :-\